# Grouping elements that each group contains only one object with specified field

Tags: java, java-stream, groupingby

I have a problem with grouping java objects. Let's look at example object:

```
public class MyObject {

    private String field1;

    public MyObject(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }
}
```

What i want to achieve is grouping `MyObject`'s in such a way that each group contains only one object with specified `field1` value. For example, for such list of elements:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    MyObject o1 = new MyObject("1");
    MyObject o2 = new MyObject("1");
    MyObject o3 = new MyObject("1");

    MyObject o4 = new MyObject("2");
    MyObject o5 = new MyObject("2");

    MyObject o6 = new MyObject("3");

    List<MyObject> list = Arrays.asList(o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6);
    List<List<MyObject>> listsWithUniqueField1Values = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to get `listsWithUniqueField1Values` looks like that:

```
[
    [
        MyObject{field1='1'}, 
        MyObject{field1='2'}, 
        MyObject{field1='3'}
    ], 
    [   
        MyObject{field1='1'}, 
        MyObject{field1='2'}
    ], 
    [
        MyObject{field1='1'}
    ]
]
```

I've tried to acheive it in effective way with using `java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy` method, but i faild.

Comment: what type of grouping is this? looks more like structuring data, could you share the specific use case or your attempted pseudo code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do with it with groupingBy. Here is my solution - I also added an autogenerated equals, hashCode, and toString

```
public class SO67140234 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyObject o1 = new MyObject("1");
        MyObject o2 = new MyObject("1");
        MyObject o3 = new MyObject("1");

        MyObject o4 = new MyObject("2");
        MyObject o5 = new MyObject("2");

        MyObject o6 = new MyObject("3");

        List<MyObject> list = Arrays.asList(o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6);
        List<Set<MyObject>> listsWithUniqueField1Values = new ArrayList<>();

        outer:
        for (MyObject obj : list) {
            for (Set<MyObject> bucket : listsWithUniqueField1Values) {
                if (bucket.add(obj)) {
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
            listsWithUniqueField1Values.add(new HashSet<>(Collections.singleton(obj)));
        }

        System.out.println(listsWithUniqueField1Values);
    }

}

class MyObject {

    private final String field1;

    public MyObject(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        MyObject myObject = (MyObject) o;
        return Objects.equals(field1, myObject.field1);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(field1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyObject{" +
            "field1='" + field1 + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine :) but what is `outer` here?

Comment: @PawełNowosielski It is a labeled statement. read more here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to group by instances of `MyObject`, this class needs to implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods, also `field1` should be final to avoid corruption of `hashCode` upon changing its value.

```java
public class MyObject {

    private final String field1;

    public MyObject(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public String getField1() {return this.field1;}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (null == o || !(o instanceof MyObject)) return false;
        MyObject that = (MyObject) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.field1, that.field1);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.field1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "field1=" + this.field1;
    }
}
```

`Collectors.groupingBy` cannot be used to obtain the required result, but a custom [`Stream::collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) operation may be applied to create a list of sets of unique `MyObject` instances (somewhat reminding @Rubydesic's solution but without nested loop).

```java
List<MyObject> list = Arrays.asList(o1, o4, o5, o2, o6, o3);

List<Set<MyObject>> result = list.stream()
    .collect(
        ArrayList::new, //  `Supplier<ArrayList<Set<>>>`
        (lst, x) -> {   // accumulator
            for (Set<MyObject> set : lst) { 
                if (set.add(x)) {
                    return; // found a bucket to place MyObject instance
                }
            }
            // create new bucket 
            Set<MyObject> newSet = new HashSet<>(); 
            newSet.add(x); 
            lst.add(newSet);
        },
        (lst1, lst2) -> {} // empty combiner
    );

    System.out.println(result);
```

Output :

```
[[field1=1, field1=2, field1=3], [field1=1, field1=2], [field1=1]]
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question though, which requests grouping by UNIQUE field1 and not field1 which equals each other.

Comment: @Rubydesic, you were right, I did not pay attention to the expected output; now the solution is updated to use Stream API.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a `groupingBy` itself. (Without the need of `equals` or `hashCode`)

1. First group using `field1`. This would give a map as:

```
{ 1 : [1,1,1], 2 : [2,2], 3 : [3] }
```

2. Now for each of these keys, iterate their respective lists and add each `MyObject` to a different list in `listsWithUniqueField1Values`.

a. First processing for key `1`, the list becomes `[[1]]` -> `[[1], [1]]` -> `[[1], [1], [1]]`.

b. Then key `2`, the list becomes `[[1,2], [1], [1]]` -> `[[1,2], [1,2], [1]]`.

c. The for key `3`, the list becomes `[[1,2,3], [1,2], [1]]`.

Code :

```java
List<List<MyObject>> uniqueList = new ArrayList<>();
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getField1))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .forEach(values -> addToList(uniqueList, values));
    
return uniqueList;
```

The below method `addToList` is where the unique list is populated.
`ListIterator` is used over `Iterator` in this case, as `add` method is available in  `ListIterator`.

```java
private static void addToList(List<List<MyObject>> uniqueList, List<MyObject> values) {
    ListIterator<List<MyObject>> iterator = uniqueList.listIterator();
    for (MyObject o : values) {
        List<MyObject> list;
        if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
            // the object needs to be added to a new list.
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            iterator.add(list);
        } else {
            list = iterator.next();
        }
        list.add(o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `MyObject` has a getter, one of the easiest way I can think of is to combine

- Collectors.collectingAndThen
- Collectors.groupingBy
- A LinkedList
- A method popping items from the LinkedList and inserting them inside of the result

```java
List<List<MyObject>> finalResult = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getField1, Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new)),
                map -> {
                    List<List<MyObject>> result = new ArrayList<>();
                    Collection<LinkedList<MyObject>> values = map.values();
                    while (!values.isEmpty()) {
                        List<MyObject> subList = values.stream()
                                .map(LinkedList::pop)
                                .toList();
                        result.add(subList);
                        values.removeIf(LinkedList::isEmpty);
                    }
                    return result;
                }));
```

The result is

```java
[
  [
    MyObject{field1='1'}, 
    MyObject{field1='2'}, 
    MyObject{field1='3'}
  ], 
  [
    MyObject{field1='1'}, 
    MyObject{field1='2'}
  ], 
  [
    MyObject{field1='1'}
  ]
]
```